# Receiving an Axios "Network error" whenever I try to send a GET request to my ASP.net API from React native Expo app

Tags: asp.net, react-native, axios

Whenever I try to make a simple Axios GET request to my local API, I face the issue of "Network Error" And I cannot seem to find the issue with my code. The problem does not occur when I try with a react web-app.

My cors policies in program.cs on the API:

```
            builder.Services
                .AddCors(opts =>
                {
                    opts.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                        builder =>
                        {
                            builder
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowAnyOrigin()
                            .AllowAnyMethod();
                        });
                });

  app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
```

And my Axios call code from react native app is this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "GET",
      url: "https://192.168.1.100:7089/api/IngredientTypes",
      headers: {
        "content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
      data: Data,
    })
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        if (error.response) {
          console.log(error.response.status);
        } else if (error.request) {
          console.log(error.request);
        } else {
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      });
  }, []);
```

When the app starts up it tries to call the api.

I expect a json-object that looks like this:
"data": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Dairy",
"description": "Ingredients that comes from animals(Milk, Cheese, Eggs, ...",
"imgFIleName": "",
"ingredients": null
},
{
"id": 2,
"name": "Oil",
"description": "",
"imgFIleName": "",
"ingredients": null
},
]

But what I get in the console is this:

{"DONE": 4, "HEADERS_RECEIVED": 2, "LOADING": 3, "OPENED": 1, "UNSENT": 0, "_aborted": false, "_cachedResponse": undefined, "_hasError": true, "_headers": {"accept": "application/json", "content-type": "application/json"}, "_incrementalEvents": false, "_lowerCaseResponseHeaders": {}, "_method": "GET", "_perfKey": "network_XMLHttpRequest_[https://192.168.1.101:7089/api/Barcodes"](https://192.168.1.101:7089/api/Barcodes%22), "_performanceLogger": {"_closed": false, "_extras": {}, "_isLoggingForWebPerformance": false, "_pointExtras": {}, "_points": {"initializeCore_end": 11152661.706, "initializeCore_start": 11152276.4285}, "_timespans": {"network_XMLHttpRequest_[http://192.168.1.106:8081/logs"](http://192.168.1.106:8081/logs%22): [Object], "network_XMLHttpRequest_[https://192.168.1.101:7089/api/Barcodes"](https://192.168.1.101:7089/api/Barcodes%22): [Object], "network_XMLHttpRequest_[https://world.openfoodfacts.net/api/v3/product/3017620422003?fields=product_name"](https://world.openfoodfacts.net/api/v3/product/3017620422003?fields=product_name%22): [Object]}}, "_requestId": null, "_response": "java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.", "_responseType": "", "_sent": true, "_subscriptions": [], "_timedOut": false, "_trackingName": "unknown", "_url": "https://192.168.1.101:7089/api/Barcodes", "readyState": 4, "responseHeaders": undefined, "status": 0, "timeout": 0, "upload": {}, "withCredentials": true}

Answer (score 0):

Add console.log to the error blocks to see where the console is coming from, also, try debugging on the backend, cos it seems you're getting an error from your request.